# How efficient is it to read data from cassandra specifying only the first clustering key?

Tags: database, cassandra, primary-key

Lets say I have a cassandra table with the following primary key

```
((partitionKey1, partitionKey2), clusteringKey1, clusteringKey2)
```

If I write a query like

```
SELECT * FROM my_table where clusteringKey1=clusteringKey1Value, ALLOW FILTERING
```

it is said that the cluster has to read across all the nodes which is fine, since I haven't specified the partition key.

But the data is ordered by clustering key. So shouldn't it be able to use binary search or something to figure out right row for the given clusteringKey1Value? Why does it have to scan all the rows and perform filtering?

Answer (score 1):

It is not efficient to read data in Cassandra without partition key. `partition key` is important for Cassandra as it allows Cassandra to identify the nodes where that particular cluster. 'partition key`' is like a zipcode for Cassandra to find the node pretty fast.

Consider you have a 100 nodes cluster and replicate data on three nodes. So for example your wanted data resides on node98, node99 and node100. Now you query without partition key then Cassandra does not know where that data will be found, so it has to scan all the nodes. Also `clustering key` ordering is for rows within a partition.  First you read in a partition then you it does apply binary search and other optimizations  for quick search within a partition but for reaching a partition it needs `partition key`.